# Intent orientation

Tags: android, android-intent

I know there are many posts regarding this, but I can't seem to find the solution.

I have an app which takes pictures by calling

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
    ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);}
else{
    return context.getResources().getString(R.string.cap_NoCam);
}
```

When the picture has been taken and it shows the preview before you save, I notice that the screen orientation seems to rotate, even when device is stationary. Once I save, my screen orientation switches to landscape, even when holding the device portrait. This results in my application being destroyed twice, once to rotate to landscape and then once after rotating back to portrait.

When I hold the device landscape, the activity is not destroyed and is resumed normally.

Is there any way to prevent this, without using configChanges?

Comment: whats ur manifest looks like where u declare your this activity

Comment: "Is there any way to prevent this, without using configChanges?" -- don't use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. You are invoking a third-party app, one that is welcome to do what it wants, such as lock the screen orientation to landscape, which is my guess as to what the problem is here. Since there are thousands of camera apps (pre-installed and user-installed), you have no guarantees regarding behavior like this.

Comment: @Syed: There manifest has not got anything special, just name, label and parent activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare: How would you suggest taking a picture then as this is the way the android documentation suggests it should be done?

Comment: can u fix the orientation in you app, if u can then try to fix the orientation of Activity in manifest like : android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: You are welcome to use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. You just have to understand its limitations, and only use it in cases where you do not care if you actually get a picture. If you want more control, use the camera APIs to write your own camera code. Note that this is complex.